# How to "sharpen" an arrowhead in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a line with an arrowhead using the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick,
        postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={
                                markings,
                                mark=at position 1 with \arrow{Triangle}
                                }
                    }
        ] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates the following diagram. The arrowhead does not really take a triangle shape, and it looks like the line sticking out the triangle arrowhead.

How would you modify the code to get a nice triangle arrowhead (without the line sticking out)?

[image]

Comment: Test the following change of your code: `mark=at position 1 with \arrow[red]{Triangle}`. You will see, that arrow is on the end of line. I don't know what is beside of your code, however, regarding to what you expect from your code, you can obtain simply with `\draw[-Triangle] (...) -- (...);`!

Comment: @Zarko Your comment is the right solution. But for the actual code posted one could also add `shorten >=1pt` to hide the end of the line.

Comment: Yes, I just try to write answer with this suggestion :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the `\arrow[red]{Triangle}` suggestion. Indeed it clearly shows that the line sticks out. The reason why I do not want to use your simple solution is that I want to modify the code later for `\tikzset` with an argument like `mark=at position #1 with \arrow{Triangle}`.

Comment: @T_T, let me clarify the problem: `\arrow` is positioned always so, that it not prolong the line. In this particular case it is left of end of line.  Since it is decoration, doesn't make any magic with line length ... I will add some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer since I don't know what is behind  your intention to use such complicated code for drawing a simple arrow:

```
\draw[-Triangle] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

In your code the `\arrow` is positioned exactly where it had to be. To see this, see the following change to your code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick, 
        postaction={decorate, 
                    decoration={
                                markings,
                                mark=at position 1 with \arrow[red]{Triangle}
                                }
                    }
        ] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives:

[image]

Well, if you persist with your approach, you need to draw shorter line (as pointed in Alan Munn's comment. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick, shorten >=\pgflinewidth,
        postaction={decorate, 
                    decoration={
                                markings,
                                mark=at position 1 with \arrow{Triangle}
                                }
                    }
        ] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Note:**
`\arrow` is always positioned  so that it does not extend the line. In your particular case it is placed at the end of the line. Since it is a decoration, it doesn't make any magic with line length (so you should draw it accordingly shorter). In the above MWE suggests how to do this manually, but according to your comment, this seems not to be the correct solution, since  if you select a different positioning of the decoration, for example `0.5`, the line will appear shorter by the line width. This can be disturbing in your drawings. So the correct solution is not to use decoration position `1` and for such position rather use a simple arrow line (as shown on the beginning of the answer).

**Addendum:**
Another possibility is to test if the desired position is `1`. If it is not, then use your decoration design, if it is, than consider the MWE above:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
decor/.style = {very thick, 
        postaction={decorate, 
                    decoration={
                                markings,
                                mark=at position #1 with \arrow[red]{Triangle}
                                }
                    }% end of postaction
                },
decorif/.code = {\ifnum 1= #1 
                    \tikzset{decor=#1,shorten >=\pgflinewidth}
                 \else 
                    \tikzset{decor=#1}
                 \fi
                },
                ]
    \draw[decorif=1]    (0,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[decorif=0.5]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red colored arrow head is only for demonstration purpose :)

Comment: @T_T, I added to my answer.See, if it can help in your drawing decorated lines.